# How Do I Make A QR Code?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Do you have to print it off of a computer, how do you get it on the computer? I know how to scan one, I just can't seem to make one.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a QR code in-game:

1. Go to the Able Sisters' shop, and speak to Sable to use the sewing machine
2. Select "Create a QR Code"
3. Choose the design you want to turn into a QR code, then tap "Confirm"
4. A QR code will then be shown on the screen, and you will be notified that an image containing the code has been saved to your device's SD card

To transfer the image to your computer, you must use an SD card reader to view the contents of your 3DS's SD card. Alternatively, you could take a picture of the generated QR code on your 3DS screen with a mobile phone, but the quality of the image might not be high enough for others to scan, depending on your phone and the complexity of your design.